# Spring Cloud Task without persisting metadata to database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-task

I want to create a `Spring cloud task application` (with `@EnableTask`) that saves its output to a relational database but at the same time I dont want it to save metadata for `taskExecution` on my database. 
I want to force it to always use in-memory map for its internal task metadata.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to achieve this by manually initializing DefaultTaskConfigurer bean and passing null value to its dataSource. 
See below:

```
   @Bean
   @Primary
   DefaultTaskConfigurer taskConfigurer() {
        DefaultTaskConfigurer taskConfigurer = new 
        DefaultTaskConfigurer(null, TaskProperties.DEFAULT_TABLE_PREFIX);
        return taskConfigurer;
    }
```